# Prevent auto concat string to url

Tags: javascript

This problem occurs only on my laptop in both Chrome and Firefox browsers.
I have a service to get data form server.

```
function add(label) {
    var url = host + "/rest/labels/";
    var request = $http({
        method : 'post',
        url : url,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        data : label
    });
    return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

If I debug, I get `url: http://example.com/rest/labels/`. But in Network Debug, it seems to be sending `url: http://example.com/web/example.com/rest/labels/` so it returns 404.

In other systems it works well and If I run it in `localhost` it works well too.

Is there any problem in my system? and how to fix it?

Comment: What is your `host` variable set to?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 var host = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"
</script>

Comment: my guess you need `var url = "//" + host + "/rest/labels/";`

Comment: You have a space in the question between `//` and `abc.com`. Is it just a typo?